# Integral solution using modified Bessel function of order 1

Tags: improper-integrals, bessel-functions

How to solve this integral making use of Modified Bessel function of order one?

$\frac{q\gamma b}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\gamma ^{2}\nu ^{2}t^{2}+b^{2})^{-3/2}\exp (i\omega t)dt$

Context: I was determining the power spectrum of pulse of virtual radiation for which I had:
$E_{x}=-\frac{q\nu \gamma t}{(\gamma ^{2}\nu ^{2}t ^{2}+b ^{2})^{3/2}}, E_{y}=\frac{q \gamma b}{(\gamma ^{2}\nu ^{2}t ^{2}+b ^{2})^{3/2}},E_{z}=0$,
$B_{x}=0,B_{y}=0,B_{z}=\beta E_{y}$

I had to use the fourier transform:

$\hat{E}(\omega )=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int E_{y}(t)\exp (i\omega t)dt$
from which I get the above Integral.

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Usually, "context" is taken here to include your thinking about the problem up to now, which can help others tailor their answers appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, shall I edit my Question?

Comment: Yes, for one you're more likely to get responses in the first place that way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Travis.

Comment: Glad to help, enjoy your stay here. :)

Comment: Looks like a fourier transform

Comment: @TylerHG yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Simplify your life by letting $a=\gamma\nu$, followed by forcefully factoring *a* outside the radical sign.
- Further simplify your life by using the [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of the functions involved, namely $(-x)^2=x^2$, $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$, $\cos(-x)=\cos x$. $\big($[Obviously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula), $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x\big)$.
- Connect this latter simplified expression with one from [this list](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32), such as $10.32.11$, for instance.
- Notice that by using an appropriate [hyperbolic substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Hyperbolic_functions), similar [formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1) can be applied.
- If you're allowed series only, expand the integrand using the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), then switch the order of summation and integration.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lucian.
I followed your hints and finally found the integral coming out to be $\frac{qb}{\pi \gamma ^{2}\nu ^{3} }K_{1}(\frac{b\omega }{\gamma \nu })$
but in the textbook they have mentioned it in the form $\frac{q}{\pi b\nu }\frac{b\omega }{\gamma \nu }K_{1}(\frac{b\omega }{\gamma \nu })$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @bpr3003: I don't really know, since I don't actually have your computations in front of me $($my result agrees with the book's$)$, but, whatever your mistakes, they are trivial. For some reason, you seem to have an *extra a* in the denominator, and a *missing w* in the numerator.

Comment: Oh yeah, there was a trivial mistake, I forgot to write few terms of the function. Finally, got the answer. Thank you again :)